# Laravel if check condition always true in patch

Tags: php, laravel

so I have `vuejs` component with favorite button to toggle favorite on items I'm able to do it locally by saving it on cookies, then I'm trying to use the button to save in to database by sending it to controller using `PATCH` method.

The value is sent to controller successfully, but when I'm doing the checking whether the button is clicked on state favorite or unfavorite, it always always checking on `true` condition.
when I'm dump it, it change correctly the request changed based on what button I press (`$favorite` is `true` when I click favorite button, `$favorite` changed to `false` when I click unfavorite button)

**`vuejs` Method :**

```
toggleFav(id, content) {
            //Everytime button is clicked, change the value of the isFavorite to manipulate button style
            this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite;
            //check if it is favorite
            const currentCookies = [VueCookies.get("FavId")];
            let arrayCookies = [];

            if (this.isFavorite) {
                let favourite = true;
                //set the cookie to id passed
                arrayCookies.push(currentCookies);
                arrayCookies.push(id);
                VueCookies.set("FavId", decodeURI(arrayCookies));
                this.$inertia.patch(
                    this.route("addfavDB", [content, id, favourite])
                );
                // console.log("UID : " + id + " Favourited");
            } else {
                let favourite = false;
                //if the favorite button pressed again it will remove the current id in the cookie
                //without removing all the cookies
                const removeCookies = currentCookies.toString();
                const removed = removeCookies.replace(id, "");
                VueCookies.set("FavId", decodeURI(removed));
                this.$inertia.patch(
                    this.route("addfavDB", [content, id, favourite])
                );
                // console.log("UID : " + id + " UnFavorited");
            }
            // console.log("Current Favourited ID = " + VueCookies.get("FavId"));
        },
```

**route :**

```
Route::patch('docs/plants/{content}&{id}&{favourite}', [PlantCharacteristicController::class, "addFav"])->name('addfavDB');
```

**controller function :**

```
public function addFav(){
        $id = request('id');
        $content = request('content');
        $favourite = request('favourite');
        // dd($isFav);

        if($favourite){
            dd('added to db');
        }else{
            dd('removed from db');
        }
        // return ;
    }
```

In controller function `$favorite` always return true no mater what I press although the requested variable is correct when I dump it before the `if else` statement, how did I go wrong ?

Comment: Check your types. You have a truthy check on `$favorite`, but it's probably not coming in as a boolean. Instead, it's likely a string set to "false". Strings are only false if they're empty or "0".

Comment: Ahh turns out the `$favorite` is comes as string instead of boolean. I've converted it to boolean using `filter_var(request('favorite'), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN)` then doing the checking and it worked ! 

thanks for pointing it out